# Sum using recursion

Tags: recursion, type-conversion

Apologies for the basic question, I'm new to java and have been stuck on this for days.
I need firstly to convert letters to numbers and then using recursion to get the sum of those numbers. I think I am close but I'm also aware it very messy

```
     public static void main(String[] arg) {

    String str= "11"; 

    //////////////////////////

    String s = "helloworld";
    String t = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (!t.isEmpty()) {
            t += " ";
        }
        int n = (int)ch - (int)'a' + 1;
        t += String.valueOf(n);
    }
    System.out.println(t);

    //////////////////////////////

     int sum=0;
     int x=Integer.parseInt(t);
     int y=recursion(x);
     System.out.println("The Sum of the digits is: "+ y);

 }   

public static int recursion(int y) {
  if(y/10>=1) {
      int tempvar =y%10;
      int remain=y/10;
      return tempvar + recursion(remain); 
  }
  else {            
      return y;
  }

}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so first of all, this line: `int x=Integer.parseInt(t);` will crash the program in runtime because the string `t` has *spaces* in it. So you need to remove this:

```
if (!t.isEmpty()) {
     t += " ";
}
```

Second, parsing the string `t` to int is a problem, because the number in string `t` can get like very, very large. Parsing this very..very large number to an int will also produce an exception during runtime. So a better way to do this is leaving it as a string, loop over it and just add the digits in it.

I have two solutions here:

- I loop on `t` and add the digits.
- I assume you have some constraint on the size of `t` so as it can be parsed to int (or long), and then use recursion as you want.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hew";
        String t = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            int n = (int)ch - (int)'a' + 1;
            t += String.valueOf(n);
        }
        System.out.println("t: "+t);


        System.out.println("sum using string: " + getSumUsingString(t));
        System.out.println("sum using int: " + getSumUsingLong(Long.parseLong(t), 0));
    }

    // the string function
    private static long getSumUsingString(String t) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
            sum += t.charAt(i)-48;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // recursive function
    private static long getSumUsingLong(long num, long sum) {
        if (num==0) return sum;
        sum += num % 10;
        return getSumUsingLong(num / 10, sum);
    }
}
```

Note:

> You can use for example, [BigInteger](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/) class in Java to deal with very large numbers if you really need to parse this string `t` to a number.

Comment: Thank you very much